# IndexError: index out of range in self when using summarization, hugging face

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm getting an error when attempting to run this code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

video_id = 'wK4XmXJ299k'

transcript = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(video_id)

corpus = ' '.join([line['text'] for line in transcript])

from transformers import pipeline
mysummarization = pipeline("summarization")
mysummary = mysummarization(corpus)
mysummary[0]['summary_text']
```

The code gets a transcript from a YouTube video and attempts to summarize with the Hugging Face Transformers model.  The error is `IndexError: index out of range in self.`

I am also seeing a `No model was supplied, defaulted to sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6 and revision a4f8f3e (https://huggingface.co/sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6). Using a pipeline without specifying a model name and revision in production is not recommended. Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (11628 > 1024). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors` message as well.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The message being given about not supplying a model pretty clearly explains why you're getting an IndexError (it literally says you'll get one in the last sentence).  You'll have to find an available model that can handle a sequence > 11628 tokens in length, or you'll have to break your transcript into smaller pieces of < 1024 tokens in length and process each piece separately before combining, or find a transformer that will break it into less than 1024 tokens in total.

Comment: I don't see how my comment was either arrogant or unhelpful.  The error message you posted clearly explains what the issue is and why you're getting an IndexError - you've exceeded the maximum number of tokens the model you are using (the default model `distilbart-cnn-12-6`) can handle by more than an order of magnitude. You either need to change the model being used to one that can handle that much data, or change the tokenized data to fit within the limits of the selected model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

video_id = 'wK4XmXJ299k'

transcript = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(video_id)

corpus = ' '.join([line['text'] for line in transcript[:100]]) # bcz of large text
print(corpus)
from transformers import pipeline
mysummarization = pipeline("summarization", min_length=30, max_length=90)
mysummary = mysummarization(corpus)
print(mysummary[0]['summary_text'])
```

Output -  Aaron Rodgers is fresh out of a victory over the Super Bowl champion Los Angeles Rams and Lambeau last evening on Monday Night Football . The back-to-back NFL MVP says he's looking forward to a holiday party .

Comment: Thank you!  Can you explain the meaning of the following output it provides, and strategies for a fix (if a fix is even needed)? ```No model was supplied, defaulted to sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6 and revision a4f8f3e (https://huggingface.co/sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6).
Using a pipeline without specifying a model name and revision in production is not recommended.``` @DhananjayKumaryRoy

Comment: I see the ```transcript[:100]``` is required because of the long transcript.  How would I summarize the entire transcript?

Would I need to loop through the transcript 100 lines at a time, and generate multiple summaries? @DhananjayKumaryRoy